# Is the "files" property necessary in package.json?

Tags: npm, package.json

It looks like the package will include all files (that are not ignored), even if the `package.json` has no `"files"` array.

Is that property necessary?

Comment: Somewhat related, I wanted to exclude some dirs, but include their parents. I ended up doing `"files": ["dist/*", "src/*", "!/**/__tests__"],`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Not really, you can do everything using `.npmignore` because all files are added unless otherwise stated.

You can see more [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files)

Comment: Thank you. That manual doesn't really state that all files are included by default, that's why I was wondering.

Comment: .npmignore **blacklists** files, while "files" **whitelists**. The latter is a much better strategy to avoid publishing unwanted files.

Comment: Do not use `.npmignore`. https://medium.com/@jdxcode/for-the-love-of-god-dont-use-npmignore-f93c08909d8d

Comment: Careful. npm will typically ignore your .gitignore files. If you add a .npmignore and don't pop in your .gitignore files, you're going to end up publishing your secret keys, etc into your public npm package.

Answer (score 68):

You can think of the [`files` property](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) in `package.json` as an *allowlist* of all files that should be included in a npm release and `.npmignore` as a *denylist* of all files that should **not** be included.

As a rule of thumb, for my own projects I usually use:

- `files` when my project has lots of auxiliary files like build scripts, config files, etc., that do not need to be included in a npm release
- `.npmignore` when there are only a few such auxiliary files

Both options are useful in different scenarios in my mind.

Comment: Will everything not in `files` be ignored?

Answer (score 18):

[This article makes a good argument](https://medium.com/@jdxcode/for-the-love-of-god-dont-use-npmignore-f93c08909d8d) for using the files property (a whitelist, as F Lekschas said), instead of using .npmignore. Reasons include:

- Using .npmignore causes .gitignore to be ignored, which may be
  unexpected by many developers.
- Often developers keep credentials in a
  package for development purposes, and they certainly don't want to
  include them in a production package. Using a whitelist technique
  greatly reduces the likelihood of accidently packaging stuff like
  this.

[Note that some files are included even if you don't whitelist them](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/165769683050/publishing-what-you-mean-to-publish). These include:

```
package.json
README
CHANGES / CHANGELOG / HISTORY
LICENSE / LICENCE
NOTICE
The file in the “main” field
```

Edited to address comment.

Comment: Point taken and addressed. Thanks.

Comment: `npmignore` **does not** causes `.gitignore` to be *ignored*, from daily work with both.

Comment: @vsync It does in the context of npm. Adding an npmignore file makes npm stop ignoring files in gitignore.

Answer (score 12):

When there is no `.npmignore` file, the contents of `.gitignore` will be used. So be careful when adding generated directories like `dist/`to your `.gitignore` as they might end up not being in your production tarball. When that happens, you can use the "files" array in `package.json` to include them, as includes from that file will never be excluded.